# Wrong comment alignment in xml files

Tags: android, android-studio, formatting, xml-comments

I'm using copyright comment at the beginning of every file but there is an annoying issue with xml files in Android Studio.

Using automatic code format option (CTRL+ALT+L) places comment on the first line right after `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` tag like this:

[image: wrong comment placement]

What I want however is this:

[image: correct comment placement]

I'm using recommended code style for Android

[image: Android Studio code style settings]

I've tried to find the option in the settings but with no luck.

I'm pretty sure there is a way to tell the formatter to put the comment on the separate line but maybe not available via GUI toggle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've found the way to keep it on a separate lines by selecting "Keep line breaks" option.

[image: code style settings]

It won't cause bad formatted comment to get on separate line but it won't break well formatted one as well so this half-solution is definitely better than nothing.